# Separating an array effectively

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an asbolute nightmare dealing with an array of numbers which has the following structure :

Odd numbers in the array : NumberRepresenting Week
Even numbers in the array : NumberRepresenting Time

So for example in the array :

```
index : value
0 : 9
1 : 1
2 : 10
3 : 1
```

Would mean 9 + 10 on Day 1 (Monday).

The problem is, I have a an unpredictable number of these and I need to work out how many "sessions" there are per day. The rules of a session are that if they are on a different day they are automatically different sessions. If they are next to each other like in the example 9 + 10 that would count as a single session. The maximum number than can be directly next to eachother is 3. After this there needs to be a minimum of a 1 session break in between to count as a new session.

Unfortunately, we cannot also assume that the data will be sorted. It will always follow the even / odd pattern BUT could potentially not have sessions stored next to each other logically in the array.

I need to work out how many sessions there are.

My code so far is the following :

```
for($i = 0; $i < (count($TimesReq)-1); $i++){
    $Done = false;
    if($odd = $i % 2 )
    {
    //ODD WeekComp
        if(($TimesReq[$i] != $TimesReq[$i + 2])&&($TimesReq[$i + 2] != $TimesReq[$i + 4])){
        $WeeksNotSame = true;
        }
    }
    else
        {
        //Even TimeComp

        if(($TimesReq[$i] != ($TimesReq[$i + 2] - 1))&& ($TimesReq[$i + 2] != ($TimesReq[$i + 4] - 1)))
        $TimesNotSame = true; 
        }
    if($TimesNotSame == true && $Done == false){
    $HowMany++; 
    $Done = true;
    }
    if($WeeksNotSame == true && $Done == false){
    $HowMany++;
    $Done = true; 
    }
$TimesNotSame = false;
$WeeksNotSame = false;
    }
```

However this isn't working perfectly. for example it does not work if you have a single session and then a break and then a double session. It is counting this as one session.

This is, probably as you guessed, a coursework problem, but this is not a question out of a textbook, it is part of a timetabling system I am implementing and is required to get it working. So please don't think i'm just copy and pasting my homework to you guys!

Thank you so much!

New Code being used :

```
if (count($TimesReq) % 2 !== 0) {
//throw new InvalidArgumentException();
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($TimesReq); $i += 2) {

    $time = $TimesReq[$i];
    $week = $TimesReq[$i + 1];

    if (!isset($TimesReq[$i - 2])) {
        // First element has to be a new session
        $sessions += 1;
                $StartTime[] = $TimesReq[$i];
                $Days[] = $TimesReq[$i + 1];
        continue;
    }

    $lastTime = $TimesReq[$i - 2];
    $lastWeek = $TimesReq[$i - 1];

    $sameWeek = ($week === $lastWeek);
    $adjacentTime = ($time - $lastTime === 1);
    if (!$sameWeek || ($sameWeek && !$adjacentTime)) {

    if(!$sameWeek){//Time
    $Days[] = $TimesReq[$i + 1];
            $StartTime[] = $TimesReq[$i];
            $looking = true;
    }
    if($sameWeek && !$adjacentTime){
    }
    if($looking && !$adjacentTime){
        $EndTime[] = $TimesReq[$i];
        $looking = false;           
    }
//Week      

        $sessions += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the data gives 4 weeks in a row? Should that be recognized as 2 sessions, or should the code recognize that the requirement (to only have 3 sessions in a row) is broken?

Comment: Prior validation will mean that this won't happen. Sorry should have been more specific. Maximum will be 3 in a row until a break.

Comment: You state that even indexes (0 and 2 in your example) represent weeks, but later state that the 9 + 10 would be the same session (so there is only 1 session in your example), but if they are weeks wouldn't they be separate sessions? (at time = 1 in week 9 and at time = 1 in week 10). Or am I completely confused? Also, you mention days, but there is no data about days. Are days/weeks being used interchangeably?

Comment: My excuse for getting that wrong was because I was up till 4am trying to do this. Still haven't got it cracked either. Apologies, they were the wrong way round. Even = Time of day. Odd  = Which Week. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single total number of sessions represented in the data, where each session is separated by a space (either a non-contiguous time, or a separate day). I think this function will get you your result:

```
function countSessions($data)
{
    if (count($data) % 2 !== 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

    $sessions = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i += 2) {
        $time = $data[$i];
        $week = $data[$i + 1];

        if (!isset($data[$i - 2])) {
            // First element has to be a new session
            $sessions += 1;
            continue;
        }

        $lastTime = $data[$i - 2];
        $lastWeek = $data[$i - 1];

        $sameWeek = ($week === $lastWeek);
        $adjacentTime = ($time - $lastTime === 1);
        if (!$sameWeek || ($sameWeek && !$adjacentTime)) {
            $sessions += 1;
        }
    }

    return $sessions;
}

$totalSessions = countSessions(array(
    9, 1,
    10, 1,
));
```

This of course assumes the data is sorted. If it is not, you will need to sort it first. Here is an alternate implementation that includes support for unsorted data.

```
function countSessions($data)
{
    if (count($data) % 2 !== 0) throw new InvalidArgumentException();

    $slots = array();
    foreach ($data as $i => $value) {
        if ($i % 2 === 0) $slots[$i / 2]['time'] = $value;
        else $slots[$i / 2]['week'] = $value;
    }

    usort($slots, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['week'] == $b['week']) {
            if ($a['time'] == $b['time']) return 0;
            return ($a['time'] < $b['time']) ? -1 : 1;
        } else {
            return ($a['week'] < $b['week']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    });

    $sessions = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($slots); $i++) {
        if (!isset($slots[$i - 1])) { // First element has to be a new session
            $sessions += 1;
            continue;
        }

        $sameWeek = ($slots[$i - 1]['week'] === $slots[$i]['week']);
        $adjacentTime = ($slots[$i]['time'] - $slots[$i - 1]['time'] === 1);
        if (!$sameWeek || ($sameWeek && !$adjacentTime)) {
            $sessions += 1;
        }
    }

    return $sessions;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Which works better than my code, however it has the same fundamental problem that my code had. Which, I never really considered before your answer. The data could possibly not be sorted.

Comment: If there is the possibility of unsorted data, I think the best/easiest solution is to just sort it first. Obviously keeping the time/week pairs attached. That would probably be easier than trying to keep track of all the sessions at once.

Comment: Good point. Your function is a lot easier to follow in my mind that mine, so now I can implement the sort and run with little issues. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've added an alternate solution that will handle unsorted data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually had already implemented my own "sort" by the time I saw you had posted your updated sort. However, using your original function I need to retrieve the StartTime, the EndTime and the day of the week for each session. I have successfully been able to retrieve the StartTime + Day of the week. I've updated the code at the bottom of my question with what I am currently using. Thanks for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8129/discussion-between-user1096685-and-brenton-alker)

Comment: Okay, sorry about that 10 I mentioned earlier (wrong data). My real question was, how does this function handle multiple weeks, so that the OP can figure out how many sessions there are per week? Also, it seems that the first function does return 1 but the second returns 2 given that same array (9,1,10,1). Perhaps I fouled something up there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my little attempt at solving your problem. Hopefully I understand what you want:

```
$TimesReq = array(9,4,11,4,13,4,8,4,7,2,12,4,16,4,18,4,20,4,17,4);

// First just create weeks with all times lumped together 
$weeks = array();
for($tri=0; $tri<count($TimesReq); $tri+=2){
  $time = $TimesReq[$tri];
  $week = $TimesReq[$tri+1];

  $match_found = false;
  foreach($weeks as $wi=>&$w){
    if($wi==$week){
      $w[0] = array_merge($w[0], array($time));
      $match_found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!$match_found) $weeks[$week][] = array($time);
}

// Now order the times in the sessions in the weeks
foreach($weeks as &$w){
  foreach($w as &$s) sort($s);
}

// Now break up sessions by gaps/breaks
$breaking = true;
while($breaking){
  $breaking = false;
  foreach($weeks as &$w){
    foreach($w as &$s){
      foreach($s as $ti=>&$t){
        if($ti>0 && $t!=$s[$ti-1]+1){
          // A break was found
          $new_times = array_splice($s, $ti);
          $s = array_splice($s, 0, $ti);
          $w[] = $new_times;
          $breaking = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

//print_r($weeks);

foreach($weeks as $wi=>&$w){
  echo 'Week '.$wi.' has '.count($w)." session(s):\n";
  foreach($w as $si=>&$s)
  {
    echo "\tSession ".($si+1).":\n";
    echo "\t\tStart Time: ".$s[0]."\n";
    echo "\t\tEnd Time: ".((int)($s[count($s)-1])+1)."\n";
  }
}
```

Given `$TimesReq = array(9,4,11,4,13,4,8,4,7,2,12,4,16,4,18,4,20,4,17,4);` the code will produce as output:

```
Week 4 has 4 session(s):
    Session 1:
        Start Time: 8
        End Time: 10
    Session 2:
        Start Time: 11
        End Time: 14
    Session 3:
        Start Time: 16
        End Time: 19
    Session 4:
        Start Time: 20
        End Time: 21
Week 2 has 1 session(s):
    Session 1:
        Start Time: 7
        End Time: 8
```

Hope that helps.